# Secureimage in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

So I wan't to use secureimage on CI coz' I don't want to use the default CAPTCHA helper since it doesn't have an audio option but I have a problem displaying the audio when using secureimage.

I copied the whole secureimage folder that I downloaded from the site to the library of CI.

Displaying the image is fine and also checking the inputted code. But my problem is displaying the audio file. I have no idea how to do it.

Here is how I displayed the image and for checking (already used the secureimage library):

```
function captcha_image(){
    $img = new Securimage();
    return $img->show();
}

public function captcha_check(){
    $img = new Securimage();
    $input = $this->input->post('imagecode');
    $result = $img->check($input); 


    if($result)
        $message = "success";
    else
        $message = "try again";
}
```

My view:

```
<img src="<?php echo site_url('form/captcha_image') ?>" alt='captcha' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this library 
https://github.com/subdesign/CI-HTI-Securimage

So The Method to get the Audio file is

> $img->outputAudioFile();

But you have to configure ( settings ) the audio path directory and make sure its rewritable

```
$settings['audio_path'] = '....';// If you didn't configure this it will secureimage library path and follow by dir /audio/
$settings['audio_noise_path'] = '...';//save as above audio path
$settings['audio_use_noise'] = true; // true or false;
$settings['degrade_audio'] = true; // true or false; 

// Then init the secureimage with the options 
$img = new Securimage($settings);
$img->show(); // this will show the image src 
$img->outputAudioFile(); // this will output the audio file to the browser
```

Comment: should i call the $img in my view?

Comment: @KairiSan you can call it in the controller or the view if you pass it from the controller.